# Passar uma propriedade para um Label no xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso fazer com que o Label do meu código receba o valor de uma propriedade.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Ponto" 
               FontSize="20" TextColor="WhiteSmoke"               
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Ponto" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                Text="+1" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20"
                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                Text="+1" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20"
                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
                Text="-1" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20"
                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                Text="-1" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20"
                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"></Button>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Você está utilizando o modelo MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o modelo MVVM, adicione uma propriedade na sua ViewModel **(lembrando que sua ViewModel deve implementar a interface INotifyPropertyChanged, vou deixar um exemplo)**.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms

public class ExemploViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()]string name = null)
     {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }

     private string _titulo;
     public string Titulo
     {
        get { return _titulo; }
        set { _titulo = value; OnPropertyChanged("Titulo"); }
     }
}
```

Na sua Label faça o Binding com a propriedade.

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
       Text="{Binding Titulo}" 
       FontSize="20" 
       TextColor="WhiteSmoke"               
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
```

No code behind (xaml.cs) da sua página, atribua a ViewModel ao seu Binding Context:

```
public ExemploView(PerfilCadastroViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new ExemploViewModel();
}
```